# If the rat starts at room 2 what is the probability of eventually ending up in room 5?

Tags: calculus, probability, matrices, markov-chains

I have a following doubt on a question of Markov chain.

[image]

I have done the parts (a) to (d). I am facing problem with the last part. I am attaching what I have done so far.

[image]

Comment: You have to find the steady state distribution. The answer to part $(e)$ is the probability component of the steady state vector corresponding to room $5$. Possibly ensure that the initial configuration $(0,0,1,0,0)$ converges to the steady state distribution.

Comment: Since there are absorbing states the stead state vector is not unique... @ShubhamJohri

Comment: Have you tried to find the steady state vector that $(0,0,1,0,0)$ specifically converges to? I think it's $[1/4,3/4,0,0,0]^t$ so your answer should be $3/4$, as per Wolfram.

Comment: They may have used the wrong word, but the idea remains the same.  The point is that given an absorbing markov matrix of the form $A=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S\\\hline 0&R\end{array}\right]$ the limiting matrix (*or whatever you want to call it*) will be $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A^n = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}I&S(I-R)^{-1}\\\hline 0&0\end{array}\right]$.  You are tasked with looking at and interpreting $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}A^n b$ where $b=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Answer (score 1):

(e) can be solved without explicit Markov machinery. Let $p_n$ be the probability of reaching room $5$ given that the rat is currently in room $n$. We have a linear system
$$p_2=\frac12(1+p_3)$$
$$p_3=\frac13(p_2+0+p_4)$$
$$p_4=\frac12(1+p_3)$$
Solving this linear system gives $p_2=\frac34$.